# ADD line in a default table model in Java

Tags: java, jtable

I've created a jtable using jframe with 3 columns, now I'm trying to add a specific number of lines informed by the user, but my table it's always empty after using my add line method.

```
package cpm;

import static java.lang.Integer.parseInt;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;


public class tela extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public tela() {
        initComponents();
        DefaultTableModel modelo = (DefaultTableModel)jTable1.getModel();
        String quantidade = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Informe a quantidade de atividades");
        int qtd = parseInt(quantidade);
        for (int i = 0; i == qtd ; i++) {
            modelo.addRow(new Object[]{"","",""});
        }
        jTable1.setModel(modelo);
    }



    public static void main(String args[]) {

       java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new tela().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTable jTable1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    // End of variables declaration                   


}
```

I've used the graphic design of Jframe to create the columns.

Comment: change `i == qtd` to `i < qtd`

Comment: Thanks! It worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to add a specific number of lines informed by the user

Use the `setRowCount()` method of the `DefaultTableModel`.

It will add empty rows of data, which is what you appear to be doing.